# Can you duplicate actions in Adobe LiveCycle Designer?

Tags: forms, pdf, action, livecycle, pdf-form

I've recently started creating a order form which will automatically fill in either the item description, product number, or unit price once selected either the product number or item description from the drop down box.

I made a smaller trial version of this form and it worked perfectly however adding all the possible 'actions' for when selecting from the drop down box took a very long time. The real order form will have a lot more items to choose from therefore will take even more time, which I don't have.

Is there a way to copy the actions I  have for the first row (Product01, Description01, Unit01) for the rest of the rows in the order form, all I would need to change is the Product01 to Product02 etc etc.

*This is what my table in my order form looks like:*

> **Product Number | Item Description | Quantity |  Unit Price | Total |**
>   
> PN01.....................| Description01........|QTY01.....| UNIT01.......|TTL01 |
>   
> PN02.....................| Description02........|QTY02.....| UNIT02.......|TTL02 |
>   
> PN03.....................| Description03........|QTY02.....| UNIT02.......|TTL03 |

*This is the code for one of the actions:*

```
//-
//+ GENERATED - DO NOT EDIT (ID:5F8FCFED-90F7-48DF-9CDA-91C02E1BC86F CRC:3737938537)
//+ Type: Action
//+ Result2: SetFieldValue("$Node3","tovalue","4.99")
//+ Result1: SetFieldValue("$Node2","tovalue","Quality safety spectacles")
//+ Node3: topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].UNIT_01[0]
//+ Node2: topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].Description_01[0]
//+ Node1: topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].PN01[0]
//+ Condition1: ListField("$Node1","textselected","NB04B")
//+ ActionName: PN01.change
if ($.boundItem(xfa.event.newText) == "NB04B") {
    this.resolveNode("Description_01").rawValue = "Quality safety spectacles";
    this.resolveNode("UNIT_01").rawValue = "4.99";
}
```

I just used the action builder to create these actions.

I hope this helped explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You should create table with a single body row and let user add new rows  when needed. Then it is enough to put the above code for cell in a single row. When new rows are added they also have this code.

In order to enable user to add new rows you can add a button with scripts that adds new row. It can be genarated using ActionBuilder. Don't forget to enable *Repeat Row for Each Data Item* for your row in Object->Binding toolbox.